# saving a form and checking if it exists already

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a method for adding a product to a `cart`. Now each product, can have `product_attributes`. Essentially what I want is to check if a product with the same attributes have been added to the cart. If so I'd like to increase the quantity of that by 1. If not, I'd like to add that product with it's attributes to the cart.

The important factor here is that I need to check the `line_item_attributes` for products with the same id, to see if their attributes matches.

```
  def add_product(product_id, instruction, attributes)
    values = attributes.values
    attribute_values = values.map { |attribute| attribute[:product_attribute_id].to_i }.compact

    similar_items = line_items.where(product_id: product_id)

    similar_items.each do |item|
      if item.line_item_attributes.map(&:product_attribute_id).sort == attribute_values.sort
        item.quantity += 1
      end
    end

  end
```

this is what I have so far, the attributes is essentially a hash like this:

```
{"0"=>{"product_attribute_id"=>"4"}, "1"=>{"product_attribute_id"=>"7"}}
```

now if I try to save this using my create action I get this error:

```
undefined method `save' for []:Array
```

Here's my controller create action

```
 def create
    product = Product.find(params[:line_item][:product_id])
    instruction = params[:line_item][:instruction]
    attributes = params[:line_item][:line_item_attributes_attributes].to_unsafe_h

    @line_item = @cart.add_product(product.id, instruction, attributes)
    respond_to do |format|
      if @line_item.save
        format.html { redirect_to store_url(product.store), notice: 'Line item was successfully created.' }
        format.js { @current_item = @line_item }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @line_item }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @line_item.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

Ruby has implicit returns.  This means that the last object in your method will be the return value.  The last object in your method is an enumerable (each) the return value of which is the collection being iterated over.  Since where returns an array, you are returning an array with your add_product method.